# Convert dataframe to corpus

Tags: r, quanteda

I use the example from [here]: https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/topicmodel/

```
`require(quanteda)
require(quanteda.corpora)
require(lubridate)
require(topicmodels)
corp_news <- download('data_corpus_guardian')`

`corp_news_subset <- corpus_subset(corp_news, 'date' >= 2016)
dfmat_news <- dfm(corp_news, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords('en')) %>% 
     dfm_remove(c('*-time', '*-timeUpdated', 'GMT', 'BST')) %>% 
     dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.95, termfreq_type = "quantile", 
              max_docfreq = 0.1, docfreq_type = "prop")
 dfmat_news
Document-feature matrix of: 6,000 documents, 4,534 features (97.2% sparse).
 str(corp_news)
List of 4
 $ documents:'data.frame':  6000 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ texts  : chr [1:6000] "London masterclass on climate change | Do you want to understand more about climate change? On 14 March the Gua"| __truncated__ "As colourful fish were swimming past him off the Greek coast, Cathal Redmond was convinced he had taken some gr"| __truncated__ "FTSE 100 | -101.35 | 6708.35 | FTSE All Share | -58.11 | 3608.55 | Early Dow Indl | -201.40 | 16120.31 | Early "| __truncated__ "Australia's education minister, Christopher Pyne, has vowed to find another university to host the Bjorn Lombor"| __truncated__ …`
```

and as we can see there is a 97.2% sparse level.
Additionally the structure of corp_news$documents$texts contains the different levels of documents.

In my case I have a dataframe (every row is a document):

```
`df <- data.frame(text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <code> ste </code> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.", "<code> teft </code> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electro <code> type sth but you can't see it </code>"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
```

I use this to remove some noise:

```
`mytext <- paste(unlist(df$text), collapse =" ")
mytext2 <- gsub("<code>.+?</code>", "", mytext)
cleanFun <- function(htmlString) {
    return(gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString))
}
mytext3 <- cleanFun(mytext2)
df2 <- gsub("\n", "", mytext3)`
```

However is that the document is unlisted and I receive sparse 0.0%
`myDfm <- dfm(df2, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords('en')) 
myDfm
Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 28 features (0.0% sparse).`

How is it possible to make df2 have the structure of every row like the df?

Comment: Why are you concatenating the text-strings into one string with `paste(collapse=" ")`? Since the number of the document in df2 is one, dfm is of course 0% sparse as every feature in the dfm must be presented in that single document in df2.

Comment: @amatsuo_net is it correct to have df2 as it is?

Comment: The problem here is the `paste(..., collapse = " ")`, which pastes the individual elements of the vector together into a single element. So when you create the dfm, you get a single document. Since all of your features are taken from the single document, it will by definition be 0% sparse. To get the individual documents, don't paste the elements together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the question is but if you want to clean the text in `df` and then convert it to a corpus, here would be the way to go:

```
df$text <- gsub("<.*?>", "", df$text)
corp <- corpus(df, text_field = "text")
dfm <- dfm(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords('en'))
> dfm
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 32 features (62.5% sparse).
```